# Getting error in Facebook Release Keyhash

Tags: android, google-play-console

Getting error in Facebook Signin (Beta release) :

"Invalid key hash. The key hash DA........g= does not match any stored key hashes.. "

We got the release key hash as 
keytool -exportcert -alias test -keystore "D:\KeyStore\test.jks" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64

Comment: are you using that same keystore file for signing your apk?

Comment: @HardikMaru : Yes

Comment: I was also facing same issue in past, I set SHA1 which I get from Gradle signingReport, it gives results for debug key not your key store. In that case we have to do manually with command which you did. Also these SHA1 is different on different devices. So if you're finding SHA1 from different device and making build from different device will also not work.